# How do you copy the newest file by creation date by applescript?

Tags: file, date, copy, applescript, plist

I'm telling a program to backup with applescript then after its done backing up I tell it to read and open the backup location from a plist file. After that I need it to copy the newest create date to a specific file on the Desktop.

```
try
    tell application "xxxxx"
        backup
    end tell
on error errmsg
    display dialog errmsg buttons {"xxxxx Backup Failed"}
end try

set the plistfile_path to "~/Library/Preferences/com.xxxxx.Xxxxx.plist"

tell application "System Events"
    set p_list to property list file (plistfile_path)
    value of property list item "backupPath" of p_list
    open result

    tell application "Finder"
        set itemGroup to sort (get every document file of the front Finder window) by creation date
        duplicate of (item 1) of the (front Finder window) to folder "LOGS-I-NEED:"
    end tell
end tell
```

I got it to duplicate the first or last file in the folder but I need to copy the newest create date file which is going to be within the last 10 seconds.  The folder I need it to be copied to is LOGS-I-NEED which will be on the Desktop.

I admit I'm new to applescript (3 weeks into applescript) and haven't really found a way that I understand to write this in applescript.

Thanks for you guys help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing your tell Application "Finder" block with this one:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set itemGroup to sort (get every document file of the front Finder window) by creation date
    set now to current date
    set sec to 10
    repeat with currentItem in itemGroup
        if (now - (creation date of currentItem)) ≤ sec then
            duplicate currentItem to folder "LOGS-I-NEED:"
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```